# Fill color doesn't match outline color

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my example data:

```
> head(Plot,n=10)
     start     end variable value
1        0  499999  control     1
2   500000  999999  control     1
3  1000000 1499999  control     1
4  1500000 1999999  control     1
5  2000000 2499999  control     1
6  2500000 2999999  control     1
7  3000000 3499999  control     1
8  3500000 3999999  control     1
9  4000000 4499999  control     2
10 4500000 4999999  control     2
```

I want to plot rectangles (and this works), however I am not able to match fill & outline colors.
**What I have tried:**

```
MyPlot <- ggplot(Plot, aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, ymin=0, ymax=1, fill=factor(value))) +
    geom_rect(linetype=1, size=0.3, color=factor(value))
Error in factor(value) : object 'value' not found
# This should work somehow as I am getting wanted output if using this:
# geom_rect(linetype=1, size=0.3, color="black")
```

I tried to put `color` into `aes`, however `fill` and outline colors doesn't match:

```
MyPlot <- ggplot(Plot, aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, ymin=0, ymax=1, fill=factor(value),color=factor(value))) +
    geom_rect(linetype=1, size=0.3)
```

I plot everything with:

```
# I have to use pdf
pdf(paste(Variable,".pdf",sep=""),
    width = par("din")[1] * 2,
    height = par("din")[2] * 1)
print(MyPlot + scale_fill_manual(values=MyPallete))
dev.off()
```

**My questions:**

- How to use `color=factor(value)` in the first example & not to get error?
  OR
- How to match colors between `fill` and outline using second example?

Comment: Can you add an image? I do not observe any difference in colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with `scale_colour_manual`. As I am scaling fill manually I also had to scale `colour` manually.

```
MyPlot <- ggplot(Plot, aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, ymin=0, ymax=1, fill=factor(value),color=factor(value))) +
    geom_rect(linetype=1, size=0.3)
# I have to use pdf
pdf(paste(Variable,".pdf",sep=""),
    width = par("din")[1] * 2,
    height = par("din")[2] * 1)
print(MyPlot + scale_fill_manual(values=MyPallete) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=MyPallete))
dev.off()
```